# git checkout branch without checking files

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout, vcs-checkout

I have huge size of git repo in my local system with 10 different branches,
In those 10 branch the master repository is around 2 GB. when i switch from any branch1 to master branch, Git is trying to checkout all files in local system itself, how to reduce the time here.

```
  [linux@linux_001 myrepo]$ time git checkout master
   Checking out files: 100% (25765/25765), done.
   Switched to branch 'master'

   real    0m55.617s
   user    0m35.597s
   sys     0m5.002s
```

Here i have reduce 55 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to use the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309): you can clone a repo once, but check it out in multiple folders, one per branch.

That way, instead of changing your current worktree, you can simply change *folder* to the one where `master` is already checked out) and update its content with a `git pull` (incremental update, much faster)

That seems easier than trying to put in place a sparse checkout or a shallow clone.

Comment: Thanks for your help VonC.